# What's the best way to bind a form submission to a relevant state object/array (nb the form was generated by mapping over another state array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, state

Ok, this may be a little tricky to explain, but I'll try my best.

What is the best way of binding data from a form submission to an existing state array?

I have a state array that i would like to access and push another property into, but it must do this contextually, based on the form in which the data was submitted into. (ie if it data was submitted into the form generated from the mapped item of the array, then it would be added as a property to it's own array)

Forgive the explanation, but finding it really hard to put into words - i hope the code further down will help.

I have tried to use the key of the individually returned item to setState in the correct 'item' of the array and a few other things, but not been very fruitful at all.

here is my state - See 'pairs' below. it is an array, with 3 arrays inside it, each of which has 3 properties. I would like to add a 4th property to each of these, contextually depending the form I submit

```
      bank: undefined,
      bankterm: '',
      cryptos: [],
      term: '',
      error: undefined,
      pairs: [
          ["BTC", " - $", 10599.22],
          ["XTZ", " - $", 0.9703],
          ["BCH", " - $", 313.08]
      ],
      history: [],
      percent: []
    };
  }
```

here is the rendered section of this array, it spits out each item in the state.pairs, along with a form.

My intention is to be able to type a number into the form and have that added to the state.pairs[insert corresponding array here].

```
{ <ul>
          {this.state.pairs.map((pair, index) => {
            return <li key={ index }>{pair}
              <form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault();this.setState({percent: [...this.state.percent, e.target.value] })} }>
                <label>percent: </label>
                <input type='number'/>
              </form>
            </li>;
          })}
        </ul>}
```

eventually I would like to use some equations on the 3rd and 4th items in the array and spit out a figure.

but as it stands i simply cannot find a means to add a corresponding property to the correct items in the state.pairs array

Pastebin here if you feel you need extra understanding of my issues - **https://pastebin.com/KnWGAVhg**

Comment: i fully expect clarification may be needed on this one, and will happily provide to those brave souls willing to offer up advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you are looking for a way to push to a specific child array in the `pairs` array. What I would recommend is changing your data structure to an object so that each item can be retrieved/set by a key:

```js
pairs: {
  btc: {
   separator: " - $",
   value: 10599.22,
  },
  xtz: {
   separator: " - $",
   value: 0.9703,
  }
} // now you can access things like pairs.btc, pairs.xtz, etc.
```

However, if you don't want to do this, you should be able to use the *index* to access the correct item:

```
{this.state.pairs.map((pair, index) => {
    // FYI: pair === this.state.pairs[index]

    // copy the existing pairs so we're not mutating state
    let newPairs = [...this.state.pairs]

    // push our new value to the correct child  array in the copy
    newPairs[index].push(e.target.value)

    // set pairs to the new, modified pairs object
    this.setState({ pairs: newPairs })
}}
```